# Как отцентрировать простой неформатированный текст?

Tags: текст, vim

Предположим, есть простейший текст и «экран» с 40 колонками (установлено через `tw`):

```
ЗАГОЛОВОК
---------------------------------------
```

Как в *Vim* сделать так, чтобы текст «ЗАГОЛОВОК» встал посередине?  То есть, как-то так:

```
              ЗАГОЛОВОК
---------------------------------------
```

Понятное дело, что есть ответ «посчитать самому и отбить ручками», но вдруг есть готовое решение «из коробки»?

Comment: `:s#.*#\=repeat(" ",(40-strchars(submatch(0)))/2).submatch(0)`, где `40` — «ширина экрана».

Comment: `:center<CR>` центрирует текущую строку. [:center](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Acenter).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, оформите в качестве ответа?

Comment: Спасибо за предложение. Пожалуй не буду, оно того не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо участнику @stanislav-volodarskiy за более краткий ответ: команда [`center`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:center).

---

Предыдущий ответ:

Спасибо участнику @aleksandr-barakin за «пинок» в правильном направлении.  На основе его ответа написал следующую функцию на *VimScript*:

```
function! CenterText()
  let l:header = substitute(getline('.'), '[[:space:]]\+', '', '')
  let l:l = (&tw - strdisplaywidth(l:header)) / 2
  let l:headerline = repeat(' ', l:l) . l:header
  call setline('.', l:headerline)
endfunction
```